# SSO in TYPO3 multisite

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Good morning everyone.
I have two sites on the same TYPO3 instance with different domains and with shared frontend users. What is the best solution to create an SSO and make sure that a user logged in on the first site is already logged in when he opens the second site?
I tried with [SYS][cookieDomain] but I think it doesn't work in different domain or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hi SSO in general is a bit more complicated because of browser securty restrictions and there is no Common solution in the TYPO3 space.

but first of some basics technical background about cookies and browser security:
when you login to a website the server hands you a cookie (to identify your sesion).

but as these information are securty relvant only the browser sends the cookie domain only back to the same site. so my-site.com can not *set* or *read* a cookie for typo3.org

if both of your sites share a common "parent" like shop.example.com and news.example.com you can simply set `[SYS][cookieDomain]='example.com'` this is within the browser securty framework so all subdomains get the session cookie. but the browser will reject cookies set for a totally different domains.

after we have established these basics how does SSO then work if cookies can't cross domain boundaries. usuall there is a "centralized" authentcation provider. letzt call that one my-auth.com in our example.

if you want to log into my-other-site.com what happens behind the scenes is your browser is redirect to my-auth.com with paramters describing the oringin of the SSO Requet. (and you perform a login there, or use an existing session) and then get redirected to my-other-site.com (with paramters to to identify the account) and then my-other-site.com creates a news session (cookie) with that account information.

if you want give the user the feeling that they are just "magically" logged in. you need some Javascript code which comunicates wiht my-auth.com (the browser will add the session cookie of my-auth.com) so you can check if a session with my-auth.com exists. and then create a local session based on the result.

as you see the process is a bit more complex. there are some "standards" (which every vendor implements a bit different) but help you with SSO. like **OAuth** oder **OpenID** if you look at the [TYPO3 Extension Repository](https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=oauth) or [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/?query=oauth&type=typo3-cms-extension) there are some OAuth Packages availible you have to try for your self it they fit your requirements.

Oauth and Open ID are the technologies behind all the login in with [facebook / gooogle / github / ...] buttons.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I would like to stay with TYPO3 sites without integrating external services. I will try to develop the solution with javascript and session sharing.

Comment: the "centralized" service does not have to be external.

you could have somthing like `auth.my-domain.com` which runs on your TYPO3.

Comment: I can confirm that Wolffc's solution works, as this is exactly the approach I took for my multi-domain project and it works well.